# How can I format date in Odoo 10 QWeb report?

Tags: qweb, odoo-10

*t-field-option* is not working.

I have tried

```
<span t-field="o.date_invoice" t-field-options='{"format": "MM/dd/yyyy"}'/>
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using

```
<span t-field="o.date_invoice" t-field-options='{"format": "MM/dd/yyyy"}'/>
```

use

```
<span t-field="o.date_invoice" t-options='{"format": "MM/dd/yyyy"}'/>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: In v12, the date/datetime fields are python date/datetime objects and not string representations. The following python formatting will work in v12: <span t-esc="o.date_invoice.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')"/> . 
https://www.odoo.com/groups/technical-62/technical-56392463

Comment: @TirthaR no it won't work as expected if you run odoo in different languages, strftime format based on the locale and not an arbitrary language.

Answer (score 4):

For those who arrive here from search engines, you can control display of date in **form** fields using widgets.

```
<field name="date_planned" widget="date"/>
```

or,

```
<field name="date_planned" widget="datetime"/>
```

In v12, the date/datetime fields are python date/datetime objects and not string representations. The following python formatting will work in v12 reports:

```
<span t-esc="o.date_invoice.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')"/>
```

https://www.odoo.com/groups/technical-62/technical-56392463

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Odoo 12, in the when creating a purchase order in the 'Purchases' app, the datetime widget was adding too much information! I tried `t-options='{"format": "yyyy/MM/dd"}'` but that didn't work. Using `widget="date"` solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: what does one have to type in order to get the month spelled out instead of it being just numbers?

Comment: Try `MMM` or `MMMM`.

Answer (score 3):

To display localized date strings. Try the following:

```
<span t-field="o.date_invoice" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;date&quot;}" />
```

Comment: Note to Editors: Please DO NOT EDIT &quot; as this is how it should be added in the qweb editor, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To delete the time section:

```
<span t-field="o.date_invoice" t-field-options='{"widget": "date"}'/>
```

Use `t-field-options` instead of `t-options`

Do not change the position of the quotes in `t-field-options`

This code respects the format date according to lang/country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<span t-esc="datetime.datetime.strptime(o.sale_id.confirmation_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%B %d,%Y')"/>
```

My Output is: May 28,2018

Comment: Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.date

I get this error. Can you pls help

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, you have used the correct way to format Qweb date, but sometimes there is problem in other thing and odoo gives error somewhere else. Hope trying this code may be helpful.

```
<span t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options='{"format": "d MMMM y"}'/>
```

also use this code

```
<span t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options="{'format': 'yyyy-MM-dd'}" />
```

You can also do one thing as formatting the date variable in the model itself and then show it on your QWeb report.

Comment: I think we should use `t-options` instead of `t-field-options`